# Combine 2 dictionaries with the same keys but different values in Python

Tags: python

I have these two dicitonaries, one represents the ids of people and the ids of the friends of their friends:

```
FOFDict = {0 : [1, 2, 3],
       1 : [2, 3, 4],
       2 : [0, 1, 3, 4],
       3 : [0, 1, 2, 5],
       4 : [1, 2, 6, 7],
       5 : [8, 3],
       6 : [9, 4, 7],
       7 : [9, 4, 6],
       8 : [5],
       9 : [6, 7]}
```

The other shows the ids of who they should be friends with based off of shared interests (found earlier in the code):

```
       InterestFriendsDict = {0 : ([1, 5, 8, 9], ['C', 'Java','Data','Rainbows']),
       1 : ([0], ['C']),
       2 : ([3, 5], ['Python']),
       3 : ([2, 4, 5, 6], ['Python','ramen','R','stats','prob']),
       4 : ([3, 7], ['ramen','AI']),
       5 : ([0, 2, 3, 8], ['Java', 'Python', 'R']),
       6 : ([3], ['stats', 'prob']),
       7 : ([4, 8], ['AI', 'anatomy']),
       8 : ([0, 7, 9], ['Data', 'anatomy']),
       9 : ([0, 5, 8], ['Java', 'Data', 'Rainbows'])}
```

I now have to combine these dictionaries in a way that shows the key id, then the friends of their friends AND friends they should be friends with, followed then by the shared interests of all of them. For example, the entry for id 0 and 1 would be:

```
{0: ([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9], ['C', 'Java', 'Data', 'Rainbows'],
{1: ([0, 2, 3, 4], ['C']),
...
```

I am struggling to determine where to begin with this. I thought I could just use .update or something like that, but I'm not sure because of how one dictionary has a tuple while the other does not. If you can help it, please respond without using things like defaultdict, I am a student and I'm trying to learn how to do this as vanilla as possible. Thank you!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much of a good reason to use a `dict` as opposed to, say, a `list`. But you essentially need to loop over the keys, and combine the corresponding values using the logic you require.

Comment: Whatever works really. is there a simpler solution with using list?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know your requirements, but a `dict` with keys that are just `1-...N` seems like it could just be a `list` (note, lists are indexed 0-...N, but does that really matter to you?)  But questions like "where do I start" are not really a good fit for stack overflow. It sounds like you need to understand some basics, like how to loop over your container.

Comment: If you use a list instead of a dict for the original structures, then they can be iterated in order, together. So you could say `for friend_of_friend, interested_friend in zip(FOFList, InterestedFriendsList)`. If you print those variables, you'll maybe see how you can combine them easily :). You can just use the `.append()` method to add things to this final list inside the loop.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I mean, you can loop over two dicts as well.

Comment: Alternatively, keeping them as dicts, you can say `for person in FOFDict:` and the "person" here will just be the keys of the dictionary, i.e. 0, 1, and so on. Then inside the for loop you can get the friend of friends for that person with `FOFDict[person]`, and you can get the interested friends with `InterestFriendsDict[person]`. Then to add these values to a new dict, you can just do `new_dict[person] = ...`. You'll have to initialize the new dictionary before the for loop with `new_dict = {}` or similar. (You'd have to do the same thing with a list for my above comment).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes but to make sure they iterate in order at the same time, would need to just iterate over the keys and index both. Even if Python 3.7+, we are guaranteed insertion order, not key order...not given any specifics, didn't want to make that suggestion. Either way, as you stated, a list seems more appropriate here so wanted to suggest a solution in line with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try breaking the problem down in little pieces and then glue them together. Here is a simple way to attack your problem:

```
new_dict = {}
# iterate over dictionary by calling items()
for key, val in InterestFriendsDict.items():
    # unpack the tuple you have with 2 variables just like the size of the tuple
    id_tup, interests = val
    new_dict[key] = (list(set(FOFDict[key] + id_tup)), interests)
```

So a couple things to note, a `set` has unique values so it quickly handles the repetitions. Which is then converted back into a `list` and placed inside the tuple along with the interests.

Comment: Maybe `sorted(set(...))` just because the results look sorted, although OP mentioned nothing to that effect as a part of the specification...

Comment: This works great! And thank you for the comments explaining it instead of just posting the code. I appreciate everyone's answers!